# Insert rows into the specified columns

Tags: vba, excel, insert

I have a little problem. I would like to insert the rows only in columns A - D. This code inserts a new row if it aligns with the upper value.

```
Dim z     As Integer
Dim intLR As Integer

intLR = Range("A5536").End(xlUp).Row

For z = intLR To 2 Step -1
  If Cells(z, 1).Value <> Cells(z - 1, 1).Value Then
    Cells(z, 1).EntireRow.Insert
  Else

  End If
Next z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the [`.Insert` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195769(v=office.11).aspx), passing in `xlDown` to shift rows down.

The below will only insert new cells in columns A:D.

```
Sub insertRow()
    Dim z As Integer, intLR As Integer
    intLR = Range("A5536").End(xlUp).Row

    For z = intLR To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(z, 1).Value <> Cells(z - 1, 1).Value Then
            Range(Cells(z, 1), Cells(z, 4)).Insert xlDown
        End If
    Next z
End Sub
```